# Extra email from Cron Daemon when running an email list script

Tags: php, email, cron, daemon

I have a PHP script that sends out a bi-weekly reminder to subscribers. Each time it sends out the email it also sends out an email that comes in from "Cron Daemon." When I first wrote the script, it didn't send this email, but now it does. I have a few questions about this.

This is what the email says:

```
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=((random letters and numbers here)); path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-type: text/html
```

1. What does this email mean?
2. Why is this email being sent?
3. Is there a way to stop the scrip from sending this email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cron reads the stdout/stderr of the command that gets executed, if something is written then cron sends an E-Mail.

I guess the php-executable is compiled as "cgi" or "fcgi" so it emits those headers by default.

To solve this you have apparently three possible solutions:

- Use the "cli" version of PHP
- Redirect stderr and stdout to /dev/null (that means append `> /dev/null 2>&1` to your cron command).
- Define `MAILTO=""` (see [this page](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-crontab-change-mailto-settings/)).

Comment: Thanks for the redirect tip. Even though I was using `php -q` and thinking that that would silence everything, it doesn't. It's defined in the PHP manual as suppressing HTTP header output. Appending `> /dev/null 2>&1` worked.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your PHP script is rendering something to the output.  If anything gets rendered at all, cron forwards that to the default administrator email.

There's two solutions to this:

1) Fix your PHP script to not output anything at all.  This is sometimes harder than it would seem, especially for non-trivial scripts.

2) Prevent the cron script from *ever* having an output.  The drawback to this method is you won't get a notice when the script fails, either.  To stop the output, use something like this:

```
#Before
* * * * * php /path/to/script
#After
* * * * * php /path/to/script > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: I'm well versed in PHP, but no always knowledgeable with some of the more technical conversations (that's what happens when you use Google to learn programming). By preventing the script from having any output, are you talking passing variables, or something more subtle like header information? Should I post some of my script to have you help me figure out what needs to be fixed?

Comment: No output means nothing written to the command line.  There are several things that can help: Don't put the closing `%>` on your script (recommended by a lot of PHP code), avoid using `echo` or similar statements, and make sure that there is nothing rendered between `%>` and `<%` tags.  Also, some methods in PHP write directly to the output.  You could post if you want.

Comment: Also, I think there is a good chance that vstm's update above may be the correct answer, given your message content.

Comment: I have the hosting done through GoDaddy.com and this is the command line I have right now:

/web/cgi-bin/php5 "$HOME/html/email-events.php"

How should I change that?

Comment: Add `> /dev/null 2>&1` to the end.