# How to stop cron daemon from warning about empty emails

Tags: email, cron

I am running a cron job which delivers a mail with a custom subject. The crontab entry is similar to :

```
python script.py 2>&1 | mail -s "Custom Subject" user@gmail.com
```

The mail from the `mail -s` is delivered to the `user@gmail.com` inbox just fine. But `user@gmail.com` receives an extra mail from the `cron-daemon` with the subject as `python script.py 2>&1 | mail -s "Custom Subject" user@gmail.com` and the email body being a warning about an empty mail being delivered. I am not sure where this extra email is originating from and would really like to know how to stop it.

Maybe related to: [Extra email from Cron Daemon when running an email list script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952082/extra-email-from-cron-daemon-when-running-an-email-list-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are probably getting the (empty) output of the `mail` command.

Try

```
python script.py 2>&1 | mail -s "Custom Subject" user@gmail.com  >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Alternatively, set

```
MAILTO=""
```

at the beginning of your crontab.